# Rails: how do attributes become protected (without any invocation of attr_protected or attr_accessible)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the "WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type", but I don't have any calls to `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` in my code.

Is there anything else that might cause an attribute to become protected?

I'm not so keen on adding all attributes to an `attr_accessible`statement, because that becomes just one more thing to maintain.

Comment: I think `type` column is use for STI on rails so it must be protected bu default, i suggest to use another name for your column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type` attribute is reserved for internal use for single table inheritance.

You should be able to use `type` by setting the `set_inheritance_column`

```
set_inheritance_column :kind # change to something other than :type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [Rails attr_accessible does not work for :type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601739/rails-attr-accessible-does-not-work-for-type)

`:type` is your problem.